# How to remove comma from number which comes dynamically in .tpl file

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

i want to remove comma from a number (e.g change 1,125 to 1125 ) in a .tpl file.
  The value comes dynamically like `${variableMap[key]}`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
var a='1,125';
a=a.replace(/\,/g,''); // 1125, but a string, so convert it to number
a=parseInt(a,10);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should always pass the radix to `parseInt` -> `parseInt(a, 10)`; otherwise, the JS engine makes its best guess and would interpret `01125` as base 8 and convert it to `597` base 10.

Comment: Hi All, Actually i am using java freemaker template. there i want remove comma (,) from the number. The Code is <td>${variableMap[key]}</td>. Any other solution for this ??

Comment: @sree - your code must be replacing the template placeholder with the actual value somewhere. You can try modifying there only.

Comment: i try .35 and i get back 0. seem the number has to be a full number?

Comment: @user3629945 `parseInt` will drop any decimal part of the input

Comment: You don't need to escape commas in regex; they're not special characters. `/,/` is sufficient.

Answer (score 21):

```
var a='1,125'
a=a.replace(/\,/g,'')
a=Number(a)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape commas in regex; they're not special characters. `/,/` is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the below function. This function can also handle larger numbers like 123,123,123.

```
function removeCommas(str) {
    while (str.search(",") >= 0) {
        str = (str + "").replace(',', '');
    }
    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var s = '1,125';
s = s.split(',').join('');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

✨ ES2021 ✨ added `replaceAll`, so no need for regular expression:

```js
const str = '1,125,100.05';
const number = parseFloat(str.replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expression to change as it is faster than split join

```
var s = '1,125';
s = s.replace(/,/g, '');

//output 1125
```

Answer (score 0):

Incoming value may not always be a string. If the incoming value is a numeric the replace method won't be available and you'll get an error.
Suggest using isNaN to see if numeric, then assume string and do replacement otherwise.

```
if(isNaN(x)) {
    x = parseInt(x.replace(/[,]/g,''));
}
```

(Not foolproof because 'not number' doesn't prove it is a string, but unless you're doing something very weird should be good enough).
You can also add other symbols to the character group to remove other stray chars (such as currency symbols).

Comment: The comma doesn't need to be within a character class. `/,/` is sufficient.